# Bootstrap 4 styling issue with input select .form-control-lg on Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When using `form-control-lg` on a select input in Firefox, the text is getting cut off.

The code:

`<select class="form-control form-control-lg">
  <option>Large select</option>
</select>`

The result in Firefox:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/284d8.png

It seems to work fine in Safari and Chrome though. Any Firefox fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match what your presented code actually outputs. Which one are we supposed to be using to troubleshoot your issue?

Comment: You are right sorry, I've updated the code @RobertC

Comment: I'm only seeing this in 4.0-beta; it seems to display correctly in 4.0-alpha.  Can you confirm which version you're using?

Comment: I'm using 4.0beta since it's the newer one. Should I switch back to alpha?

Comment: Looks like the issue was reported 4 days ago on GitHub: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23347  ... it's purely opinion but I'd just stick with 4-Beta and apply the fix in the GitHub link.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Much appreciated.